# Comparing getValue with map.layers[i].name?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js

As part of a xtype combo, I would like to know if the layer I choose in my simple data store (represented by `this.getValue()`) is present in the map layers. So if it does, `A` should occur, and `B` if it does not. The problem is that `myLayer` variable seems to be unrecognized, even though Opera Dragonify throws no error at all.

Where would be the error?

```
listeners: {
  'select': function(combo, record) {
    for(var i = 0; i < mapPanel.map.length; i++) {
      var myLayer = mapPanel.map.layers[i].name;
      if (myLayer == this.getValue()) {
        // do A here...
      } else {
        // do B here...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop will not be entered, because you are trying to get the length of `mapPanel.map`, which will be `undefined`. Try to get the length of `mapPanel.map.layers` instead:

```
listeners: {
  'select': function(combo, record) {
    for(var i = 0; i < mapPanel.map.layers.length; i++) {
      var myLayer = mapPanel.map.layers[i].name;
      if (myLayer == this.getValue()) {
        // do A here...
      } else {
        // do B here...
      }
    }
  }
}
```